# Tkinter Python: How to continue running script without closing the messagebox popup

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, popup, messagebox

I have a doubt, how can I continue running the script without closing a messagebox from tkinter? Or show multiple messageboxes at the same time
An example:

```
from tkinter import messagebox as MB
aux = 0

def scrpt():
    global aux
    #the script stops here ⬇️
    MB.showinfo(title="Simple Program", message="aux= "+str(aux))
    #the code below isnt ejecuted if i didnt accept or close the above popup ⬆️
    aux += 1
while True:
    scrpt()
```

I want to know if there is a way to continue running the script without closing the tkinter messagebox popup.

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), why don't you explain what you are actually trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is possible with message box because I tried it with many ways but in vain, however …

you can do it by using Toplevel() class:

```
from tkinter import *

for i in range(0, 100):
    a = Toplevel()
    Label(a, text=str(i)).pack()

mainloop()
```

The problem is by closing one window all will close too, you can do this so it won't close together:

```
for i in range(0,100):
    a= Tk()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Tysm for replying and for the information, the problem here is... Im using a tkinter window as the main window for gui, so, i don't know how that could affect the main window. I tried to give you points for the answer but i still can't until reach lvl reputation 15.

Comment: i thought you wanted to do like the malicious activity prank pop ups window or something like that,

Comment: Not rlly, its because i have a lot of loops running and i need to get advised when a variable changes, but my code cant still advising if i dond close the popup window :/ i can show u the full code but i'll need to hide some variables with private information

Comment: I did some simple research, I didn't find any answers, i don't think i can help you, maybe someone else can ):

Comment: Dont worry dude, tysm for trying, im beginning to think that maybe it is impossible to do by tkinter protocols.

Comment: The first  half of this answer is good, but you shouldn't be creating windows and calling `mainloop` in a loop.

Comment: you're right, i did it by mistake, i edited it